# linq query to search from 5 arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am getting five arrays from client side, and I have five lists from which I have to show values of that rows of the database that are selected by client(which are i am getting in array). I need a LINQ query through which I can select rows from database for particular values. Here it is my controller to write query. 
Please guide me how to do this i am new to this all.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult somemethod(string[] array1, string[] array2, string[] array3, string[] array4, string[] array5)
{
    List<string> results = objUS.tablename.Select(q => q.colname).ToList();
    var USData = (from row in objUS.tablename where (row.is_deleted == false) 
                 select row); 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(array1[0])) 
    { 
          for (var item = 0; item < array1.Length; item++) 
          { 
              USData.Where(x => results.Contains(array1[item])); 
          } 
    } 
    return View(USData); 
}
```

I am getting some errors there. I have tried for one field only yet. Please guide me to do this.

I get colname's data in array. I got 5 different fields and I get data of anyone's from client. Now the thing is i need to filter or search rows from database where appropriate colname's data from database.

Comment: i have googled all around but didn't get solution yet

Comment: I don't understand your question. can you add some data?

Comment: yup sure but this is all i am having trouble. i need a query just. ok i edit one more thing

Comment: Hard to answer this since we can't tell what Entity is behind `objUS`. Also, calling `.ToList()` probably isn't the smartest thing to do; you'll drag in the entire table. Please provide some more info on your globals.

Comment: USData.Where(x => results.Contains(array1[item])); Where do you use x?

Comment: X is lambda in short it is USData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by this partialview

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AR(IList<string> array, IList<string> array, IList<string> array, IList<string> array, IList<string> array)
    {
        array[0] = array[0].ToString();
        array[0] = array[0].ToString();
        array[0] = array[0].ToString();
        array[0] = array[0].ToString();
        array[0] = array[0].ToString();

        int tempR = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);

        var USData = objUS.tableName.Where(u => u.colName == false);

        if (array.Count < 2 && array.Count < 2 && array.Count < 2 && array.Count < 2 && array.Count < 2)
        {
            function2(Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]));
        }

        if (array1.Count > 1)
            USData = USData.Where(u => array1.Contains(u.tableName.colName));

        if (array2.Count > 1)
            USData = USData.Where(u => array2.Contains(u.tablename.colName));

        if (array3.Count > 1)
            USData = USData.Where(u => array3.Contains(u.tablename.colName));

        if (array4.Count > 1)
            USData = USData.Where(u => array4.Contains(u.tablename.colname));

        if (array5.Count > 1)
            USData = USData.Where(u => array5.Contains(u.tablename.tablename.colName));
        if (tempR != 0)
        {
            if (tempR != 1)
                USData = USData.Where(us => us.colName == tempR);
            else
                USData = USData.Where(us => us.colName == null);
        }
        ViewBag.RecordCount = recordCount = USData.Count();
        return PartialView("functionName", USData);
    }
```